# Vacuuming and Analyse : Drastic change in query cost

Tags: performance, postgresql, postgis, database-administration

I have a Postgres 9.6 installation and I am running into this weird case where - if I run a same query having multiple joins after 10 to 15 mins, there is increase in the value of query cost in the order of few hundreds and its keep on increasing.

I do understand what vacuuming and analyse does, but I am worried about the query cost which starts increases within few minutes of performing vacuum and analyse. I am afraid this might lead do future performance bottlenecks.

PS: I have two table out of which one is heavily written (about 5 million records ) and other is heavily updated (70 K records with postGIS this table mostly have updates on lat lon & geom column)

Does this means I should have auto vacuum run every few hours?

Comment: Is there an increase in the query _execution time_ as well? Maybe the adjusted cost, simply reflect the real world better. Does the plan change or just the cost estimation? Do you get different execution times if you use **`explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)`** multiple times? Typically there is no need to run vacuum manually. If you have frequent updates to the table, you should make sure you have no `idle in transaction` sessions and that you make autovacuum aggressive enough to keep up with the change rate

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
So I do get different execution time when I use explain with analyse , verbos and buffer multiple times. Although the query plan does not change at all.

Answer (score 0):

Make Autovaccum aggressive; but if you think autovaccum is using up resources(by looking at cpu ]and IO usage) you could tweak-- autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay and autovacuum_vacuum_threshold paramters at table level